# Django Many-to-Many with a Model Inheritance

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm looking to use Django's `Generic` models in a `ManyToMany` style relationship where one model inherits from a base class, and the other model doesn't inherit can have multiple references to many of those inherited models, and those inherited models can also belong to many different instances of that class (e.g. in this case `Author`).  Example of the structure of my models is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Book(BaseModel):
    pass

class Article(BaseModel):
    pass
```

Among other additional models that inherit from the `BaseModel`, then I have

```
class Author(models.Model):
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    publications = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

However, this doesn't seem to a allow me to add multiple publications to the `Author` model.  In this case, all the publication sources can have many authors and authors can have many publications, but as far as `Django` admin is concerned, I can only add one publication.  Is there a similar way to do this as in `ManyToManyField`, where I can do

```
>>> a = Author()
>>> a.publications.add(Book())
>>> a.publications.add(Article())
```

Comment: GenericForeignKey can only reference a single related model, not many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the Many to Many association yourself.

Soemthing like:

```
class AuthorPublication(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='publications')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('object_id', 'content_type'),
        )
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
>>> a = Author()
>>> a.publications.add(AuthorPublication(content_object=Book()))
>>> a.publications.add(AuthorPublication(content_object=Article()))
```

Comment: Combined it with `choices`, works like a charm, thanks.